# Map.computeIfAbsent requires not null result in Kotlin

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, null

Code snippet

```kotlin
val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
map.computeIfAbsent(key) { calcValue(it) }
```

with `calcValue` signature:

```kotlin
fun calcValue(key: String): String?
```

compiles with error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

But it is acceptable for `mappingFunction` to return `null` in `Map.computeIfAbsent`.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: At the same time it works well with `compute` method: `map.compute(key) { k, v -> v ?: calcValue(k) }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was apparently explicitely not allowed by the kotlin team to simplify the usage. See explanation here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10982#focus=streamItem-27-2187715.0-0

So either use `compute` or use a nullable type as value in the map.